# Probability of picking two specific shapes

Tags: probability

You write a Java program that draws two shapes on the screen, one after another, and then terminates. Your program has eight different shapes to choose from.

In the set of eight available shapes, there is one triangle and one trapezium. What is the probability that an output of your program will contain both these two shapes? (Assume that a shape can be drawn by your program more than once.)

$8^2 = 64$ possible ways

$P(8,2) = 56$

So $56/64$?

Comment: Assuming each shape is equally likely to be any of the eight possible choices, $56/64$ is the probability that the program will draw two different shapes. The complement of that event, with probability $8/64,$ is that the program draws two copies of the same shape. But you asked for the probability of a triangle and a trapezium, not the probability of any two different shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the program has to choose one of the two "good" shapes. This happens with probability $2/8.$ Then it has to choose the one remaining "good" shape, which happens with probability $1/8,$ as the program is drawing with replacement. That leaves us with a probability of

$$\frac{2}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{32}.$$